# How can I make a quick bread mix less sweet?

Tags: baking, sugar

I have one of those quick bread mixes to which you only need to add water, oil, and eggs. The problem is that it is too sweet for my taste.

Are there any tricks to make it less sweet?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the flavor profile of mixes by adding more flour to cut the sugar. In the case of quick breads, I would suggest using self rising so that your quick breads will still have enough leavening.

Another way to cut the sweet would be to add ingredients that are savory, such as nuts or vegetables.  Depending on the mix, additions could vastly change how sweet it tastes.  They also make mixes that have reduced sugar in them that you could try.  Some of the health food mixes and specialty diet mixes (things like gluten free and vegan) might be more up your alley.

Comment: Adding savory ingredients sounds like a very good idea.  I think I'd be slightly concerned about losing some of the flakiness/mealiness with the addition of more flour and ending up with a rather glutinous quickbread (and the prepared mixes already tend to be more glutinous than a quickbread ought to be).  Depends on the quantities though, obviously.

Comment: @aaronut as long as the leavening (read baking soda) maintains the right level the crumb shouldn't be affected to much. The structure of a quick bread is created by the proteins in the egg combining with the flour, as the gluten in the flour doesn't have time to form in those types of recipes. That;s why you aren't supposed to let them sit for an extended period of time or they get tough.  At least that's how I understand it...

Answer (score 1):

Al of the above :-)  Make your own mix with more flour, less sugar and a pinch of salt.  Combine your mix with your pre-made mix and then cut in half for 2 batches.

Answer (score 0):

Add a pinch of salt. Modern breads are very low on salt.

Comment: Salt will actually enhance the sweetness, not eliminate it.

Comment: Depending on the amount of salt. Modern breads and bread mixes are low on salt. For 0,5 kg of flour, add 0,5 teaspoon of salt and it should be salty (as the question is about bread mixes) go down from that.

Comment: Maybe a small pinch of salt will enhance sweetness, but believe me, as you add salt, it will become savory in the end.